# Method Swizzling - Please explain property mapping within this implementation

Tags: objective-c, method-swizzling

I was looking into an open source pull-to-refresh control and it swizzle lifecycle methods on a UIViewController category like so:

```
- (void)INBPullToRefreshView_viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self setClearNavigationBar:YES];
    [self INBPullToRefreshView_viewWillAppear:animated];
    UITableView *tableView = self.pullToRefresh.tableView;
    tableView.contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset;
    self.pullToRefresh.showPullToRefresh = YES;
}
```

I get that when `viewWillAppear` was called it mapped to the above method, and that calling `[self INBPullToRefreshView_viewWillAppear:animated];` will map to the original `viewWillAppear`.

However, what does the following do?:

```
tableView.contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset;
```

---

Here's the [github source](https://github.com/intmain/INBPullToRefresh) for the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're asking something unrelated to the swizzling itself?

Setting the contentOffset property will cause a scrollViewDidScroll: message sent to the delegate of your object.  There's probably a cleaner way to accomplish that (or at least it should have a comment)

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect the author is trying to use a side-effect of `setContentOffset:`, perhaps forcing a recalculation. But the author seems active on the project, so why not ask intmain in a github issue?

Of course the standard warnings that this kind of method swizzling is extremely dangerous and fragile apply.